# I restored my wallet, and I chose the wrong block height to start scanning. What are my options?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, refresh, block-height

This wallet I just restored has no transactions any earlier than maybe block 800k.  Well, I told the wallet to refresh from 80k by accident.  It's taking forever to scan.  I don't want to just let the computer refresh forever.  Is the 80k located in some config file that I can edit?  Or is there a command I can enter to tell it to start at 800k?

Comment: This question applies the other way around more so, where it could have been the case that my initial block height should have been 110k, but I accidentally put 1.1M.  Of course, in that example, a scan from the beginning of the blockchain is only marginally longer than scanning from block 110k.  Still it would be nice to re-choose the initial height, for future rescans, for example.

Comment: I may be missing something, but... ^C and restart with the correct height ?

Comment: I appreciate it.  I was thinking that I'd be doing something "wrong" by exiting the process before the wallet setup was completed, or that it wouldn't ask me again for the rescan block height.  It appears that assumption was incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward (and probably convenient) way is to, like user36303 said, exit the wallet and restart the process with the correct blockheight. There is currently no command to alter the restore blockheight after you have already entered it. Furthermore, I personally don't think it would be worth to implement such a thing, because the reward is not worth the amount of work that has to be put into it.